# Create a pivot table with multiple hierarchical column groups

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a pivot table (to later be rendered in markdown). However, I can't find a way to produce  multiple pivot *columns*.

**my data**:

```
| ID | group | var1   | var2   |
| -: |:-----:|:------:|:------:|
| 1  | A     | 1      | 2      |
| 2  | B     | 3      | 4      |
| 3  | C     | 5      | 6      |
| 4  | A     | 7      | 8      |
| 5  | B     | 9      | 10     |
| 6  | C     | 11     | 12     |
```

**required table**:

```
|    |     groupA      |     groupB      |     groupC      |
| ID | var1   | var2   | var1   | var2   | var1   | var2   |
| -: |:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|
| 1  | 1      | 2      |        |        |        |        |
| 2  |        |        | 3      | 4      |        |        |
| 3  |        |        |        |        | 5      | 6      |
| 4  | 7      | 8      |        |        |        |        |
| 5  |        |        | 9      | 10     |        |        |
| 6  |        |        |        |        | 11     | 12     |
```

Obviously the result is not a dataframe or a tibble.
How can such a table be created?

Comment: Check out the `gt` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on @I_O data transformation, the header for the groups you could achieve with the `kableExtra` package, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(kableExtra)

options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'),
               names_to = 'var_name',
               values_to = 'value'
  ) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
               names_from = c('group', 'var_name'),
               names_sep = '\n', ## wrap line after group name
               values_from = 'value'
  ) %>% 
  kbl(col.names = c("ID", "var1", "var2","var1", "var2","var1", "var2")) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", "groupA" = 2,"groupB" = 2,"groupC" = 2 )) %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F)
```

[image: Kable_example]

Answer (score 2):

if this is your example data **df**:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, group = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"
), var1 = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), var2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

... you can generate the table structure and column headers like this:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'),
               names_to = 'var_name',
               values_to = 'value'
               ) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              names_from = c('group', 'var_name'),
              names_sep = '\n', ## wrap line after group name
              values_from = 'value'
              )
```

Note that AFAIK having the group names span the variable columns would require some separate fiddling between the steps of reshaping your data (see above) and producing the markdown.

Comment: Thank you!
How to transform the data itself is important. I will have to look further into creating the titles for the markdown table.

Comment: **{huxtable}** might be an option (https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/). The project page also offers a convenient comparison with other relevant packages (https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/design-principles.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using reshape2

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(
  melt(
    df,
    id.vars=c("grp1","grp2"),
    measure.vars=c("var1","var2")
  ),
  grp1~grp2+variable,
  value.var="value"
)

  grp1 A_var1 A_var2 B_var1 B_var2 C_var1 C_var2
1    1      1      2     NA     NA     NA     NA
2    2     NA     NA      3      4     NA     NA
3    3     NA     NA     NA     NA      5      6
4    4      7      8     NA     NA     NA     NA
5    5     NA     NA      9     10     NA     NA
6    6     NA     NA     NA     NA     11     12
```

Comment: Thank you.
This still doesn't explain how to make the actual hierarchical table, but now I'm half-way there :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues here. One is how to print a hierarchical table in R. There are a few ways to do this, mostly producing latex or html tables. For a hierarchical table printing in the R console, one option is to use `tabular` from the `tables` package:

```r
library(tables)
library(dplyr)

fm <- function(x) if(length(x) == 0) "" else x

tabular( (ID) ~ group*(var1 + var2)*(`---`=fm),
         data=mutate(df, ID = factor(ID), group = factor(group)))
#>                                   
#>     group                         
#>     A          B         C        
#>     var1  var2 var1 var2 var1 var2
#>  ID ---   ---  ---  ---  ---  --- 
#>  1  1     2                       
#>  2             3     4            
#>  3                        5    6  
#>  4  7     8                       
#>  5             9    10            
#>  6                       11   12
```

The second, perhaps more important issue is how to store and work with hierarchical tabular structures. This is possible with nested tibbles. In your case, we can do something like:

```r
library(tidyr)

nested_df <- complete(df, ID, group) %>% 
  nest_by(ID, group) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = data)

nested_df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      ID                  A                  B                  C
#>   <int> <list<tibble[,2]>> <list<tibble[,2]>> <list<tibble[,2]>>
#> 1     1            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]
#> 2     2            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]
#> 3     3            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]
#> 4     4            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]
#> 5     5            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]
#> 6     6            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]            [1 x 2]
```

To access, say, the var1 and var2 columns for group A we would do:

```r
nested_df %>% select(A) %>% unnest(A)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2    NA    NA
3    NA    NA
4     7     8
5    NA    NA
6    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `complete()`!